# excluding children from a firebase node with read access

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm creating a simple chat application using firebase and am running into some issues with the available security settings.

The data model for this application is very simple and is as follows

```
rooms:[
    people:[
        {
            name: //string
            status: // what the user is doing, typing, still connected etc.
            secret: // the problem is with this
        }
    ],
    messages:[
        {/* message to and payload*/}
    ]
]
```

the issue is that I only want the user that created the rooms[i].people[j] to be able to update the status of that person.

Being new to firebase I though I would be able to use the update function as follows

```
personRef.update({
    'status': // newStatus
    'secret': // used to authorize the update
})
```

the problem with this is I can't find any way to make the secret write only and give access to the people at the same time.  That is I need anyone to be able to pull the data located at rooms[i].people - meaning rooms[i].people would have to have ".read":true (in firebases security rules).  But this would give read access to every child and anyone in the room would be able to see any one else's update secret. I'm I thinking of this problem incorrectly?

Is there a way to give read access to a parent but exclude some of the children from the results?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on how you're using the person's secret to authenticate them (stored in a cookie?)  Also, how are you logging users in? simple login?

Comment: @JennyTong I'm simply storing the secret in the JS, its a single page app.  Yes, that means that if they leave and come back they have to reengage.  I believe it would be the same problem if it were stored in a cookie though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit on how you're using the secret to implement authorization, but I suspect denormalizing your data is going to do the trick.  Try something like this:

```
people-secrets:[
    <user's ID>: {
        secret: 
    }, ...
],
rooms:[
    people:[
        {
            name: //string
            status: // what the user is doing, typing, still connected etc.
        }
    ],
    messages:[
        {/* message to and payload*/}
    ]
]
```

That would allow you to segment the security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "people-secrets": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "rooms": {
      "$room_id": {
        "$user_id": {
          ".read": "auth.uid != null",
          ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid && root.child('people-secrets/' + auth.uid + "/secret") === <that token>"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Awww, so there is a unique Id given to a user even if that user is anonymous.  That's the point I was missing.  Your solution would seem to work well with then, thanks!